# Yesterday my reputation was 122 and today it's 10

Tags: support, reputation-display

Yesterday my reputation was 122 and today it's 10. Where did it go?

My email ID is [redacted, see history]. OpenID is https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=aitoawldfjhxncxmcjortysjblboopt2jd_mdys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because of one of your post got 6 spams / offensive flags, which is -100.

Do you remember any post got lots of downvotes these days?

You could check at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and look for -100 post

Comment: but can i able to see that post or not in my list of answer or questions ? no post with 6 spams.

Comment: @KuldipMCA, those posts are automatically deleted, so its not in the list of answer or questions.

Comment: ok but last day i had 122 and then -100 means 22 then why 10 reputation will display.
how i would know which post lost me my reputation ?

Comment: @KuldipMCA, check at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and look for -100

Comment: it's display my ** total rep 24 :)
so my total reputation is 24 it's display 10 currently.

Comment: @KuldipMCA, ok, to get 24, please flag one of your post to moderator attention and ask for reputation recalculation

Comment: how would i flag my post for moderate attention ?

Comment: @KuldpiMCA, There should be a link called `flag` under your posts, no?

Comment: i got it thanks sorry for so many questions but i am not clear why my reputation is lost.

Comment: No problem, @KuldipMCA. If you're not clear, can you let me know which post you got -100? there is post id on that line. So I can take a look and explain something.

Comment: 12  2818316 (-100) that is text i think 2818316 is post id which display -100 reputation.

Comment: my reputation is not updated so can you check please.

Comment: That was an answer with a blog link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause/2818316#2818316), since you answering a question from 2008 and only a blog post link, some people might think that was spam.

Comment: @KuldipMCA, once you've requested for recalc, you need to wait, because those are done manually by moderators.

Comment: ok fine i will wait for this, thanks.
and i give answer with my own blog link that is my own research i am not giving others blog link.

Comment: @KuldipMCA, yeah, I understand your effort though. -100 is bit serious, I have upvoted some of your posts, I think its worth.

Comment: thanks, Mark i really appreciate your response.

Comment: As for links to blogs: in general those are not helpful for a Q&A site. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) (Without seeing your deleted answer: maybe plain downvotes rather than flags might have been a better way to tell you that.)